# Trying to convert Optional into C#

Tags: c#-4.0, vb.net-to-c#

I'm trying to convert come vb.net code into C# but came across optional in one of the functions.

```
Private Function doOpenConnection(ByRef cn As OleDb.OleDbConnection, ByRef cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand, ByVal sConnString As String, Optional ByVal sUSP As String = "") As Boolean
```

It seems like instead of using overloading, VB.Net has an option to create it into one method/function. Does C# have a similar equilvalent or do I have to create a method for each possbility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# has an equivalent as of C# 4:

```
private bool doOpenConnection(ref OleDb.OleDbConnection cn,
                              ref OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd,
                              string sConnString,
                              string sUSP = "")
```

Note that you probably *don't* need `ref` for the first two parameters here - it's important that you understand [how parameter passing works in C#](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html).

C# 4 has both *named arguments* and *optional parameters*. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) for more information. Note that there are various restrictions, in that optional parameters have to come before required ones (aside from parameter arrays), and the default value has to be a constant (or you can use the `default(...)` operator).

Comment: Yea the original programmer had it there in his VB code. I'm just trying to convert it to c#. Thanks for the links

Answer (score 1):

You can have [optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) in C#.

**From the MSDN:**

> Each optional parameter has a default value as part of its definition. If no argument is sent for that parameter, the default value is used. A default value must be one of the following types of expressions:
>
> - a constant expression;
> - an expression of the form new ValType(), where ValType is a value type, such as an enum or a struct;
> - an expression of the form default(ValType), where ValType is a value type.
>
> Optional parameters are defined at the end of the parameter list, after any required parameters. If the caller provides an argument for any one of a succession of optional parameters, it must provide arguments for all preceding optional parameters. Comma-separated gaps in the argument list are not supported. For example, in the following code, instance method ExampleMethod is defined with one required and two optional parameters.

```
    public void ExampleMethod(int required, string optionalstr = "default string",
        int optionalint = 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}, {2}, and {3}.", _name, required, optionalstr,
            optionalint);
    }
```

Comment: if only C# had optional refs... only thing keeping my from converting